# JavaScript - Why can't I add new attributes to a "string" object?

Tags: javascript

I've experimented with JavaScript and noticed this strange thing:

```
var s = "hello world!";
s.x = 5;
console.log(s.x); //undefined
```

Every type of variable in JavaScript is inherited from object. So it should be possible to add new attributes to every object.

Did I misunderstand something wrong?

Comment: There are primitive types which don't inherit from `Object`. This is the case for string, number and boolean literals.

Comment: JS worst language type system ever

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A string in JavaScript isn't an instance of `String`. If you do `new String('my string')` then it will be. Otherwise it's a primitive, which is converted to a `String` object on the fly when you call methods on it. If you want to get the value of the string, you need to call `toString()`, as shown below:

```
var s = new String("hello world!");
s.x = 5;
console.log(s.x); //5
console.log(s); //[object Object]
console.log(s.toString()); //hello world!
```

Comment: Thanks! I never noticed that there is a difference between "hello" and new String("hello"); I logged "hello".__proto__ and got Object. So it was clear for me...

Answer (score 1):

String objects are objects and can be expanded, but string literals are not string objects and can not be expanded.

Example:

```
var s = 'asdf';
s.x = 42;
alert(s.x); // shows "undefined"

s = new String('asdf');
s.x = 1337;
alert(s.x); // shows "1337"
```

Answer (score 0):

Skilldrick’s answer explains why it doesn’t work and therefore answers your question.

As a side note, it *is* possible to do this:

```
var s = {
  toString: function() { return "hello world!"; }
};
s.x = 5;
console.log(s.x); // 5
console.log('result: ' + s); // "result: hello world!";
console.log(String(s)); // "hello world!";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `s` is a string literal, not a string object. String literals are [handled differently](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Strings_Reference):

> The reason you can't add properties or methods to a string literal is that when you try to access a literal's property or method, the Javascript interpreter temporarily copies the value of the string into a new object and then use that object's properties or methods. This means a String literal can only access a string's default properties or methods and those that have been added as prototypes.

Comment: Is that a quote? If so, from where?

Comment: Yes, it is a quote. The reference is linked right before the quote.

Answer (score 0):

[Primitives <sup>MDC docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JS/Glossary) are immutable.

> **primitive, primitive value**
>   A data that is not an object and does not have any methods.
>   JavaScript has 5 primitive datatypes: **string**, **number**, **boolean**, **null**, **undefined**.
>   With the exception of *null* and *undefined*, all primitives values have object equivalents which wrap around the primitive values, e.g. a String object wraps around a string primitive.
>     **All primitives are immutable**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
var s = "hello world!";
s.prototype.x = 5;
console.log(s.x);
```

Comment: This would add the x property to ALL string object and is not what I wanted to do ;)

Comment: Gives "TypeError: Result of expression 's.prototype' [undefined] is not an object." Anyway, even if s was a string object, objects don't inherit from their own prototype but that of their constructor, which is referenced by the internal [[prototype]] property.