# setting string properties in js

Tags: javascript, string, properties

Is it possible to somehow attach additional properties to strings in js? I am picturing something along the lines of

```
var s = "Hello World";
s.x = 'bar';

console.log(s.x);
```

Unfortunately, `s.x` is `undefined` after the assignment.

I know this question seems a little of. Why would you want to attach additional properties to a string after all? In my case the reasoning is as following: I am using a (questionably designed) library, which provides a function to create an xhr request given an url. The url is then passed to a callback function with the result.

Picture the library (`xhr`-function) similar to:

```
var xhr = function(url, cb){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data){
            // do library stuff

            // my code goes here
        }
    })
}
```

**Part of the framework is, that the callback function is not passed as a function but copied into the success handler body. This way I am able to access the url parameter in the *my code goes here*-section.**

Now in my cb-handler, I need additional data other than just the url. Is there a way to hack this on to the url parameter? Unfortunately I can't change the library :(

I was planning to do something like:

```
var xhr = function(url, cb){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data){
            // do library stuff

            // my code goes here
            // access url.foo
        }
    })
}

var url = 'https://example.com'
url.foo = 'bar'
xhr(url);
```

Comment: Strings are one of the primitive types, ie. not objects so you can't attach properties to them like this.

Comment: to attach props to string, use concat or join. str.concat('?bar=a&baz=c')

Comment: you'd have s as an object rather than a string or a function (otherwise you're mutating the expected behaviour of the string and that's unexpected and somewhat poor design)

Comment: also this question is a possible duplicate of [Why can't I add properties to a string object in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201138/why-cant-i-add-properties-to-a-string-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I add properties to a string object in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201138/why-cant-i-add-properties-to-a-string-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to  [skilldrick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5539078/2903169) on duplicate SO Question [why can i add new attr to string obj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539047/javascript-why-cant-i-add-new-attributes-to-a-string-object)

```
var s = new String("hello world!");
s.x = 5;
console.log(s.x); //5
console.log(s); //[object Object]
console.log(s.toString()); //hello world!
```

I still wouldn't advice it tho; (not exactly intuitive behaviour)